# cant install mbrola female spanish voice from ppa for espeak how I could install it?

Tags: linux, installation, espeak, mbrola

appear this error Unable to locate package mbrola-es3

how i CCould solve

this is my code

```
 sudo apt-get install mbrola mbrola-es3
espeak -v mb-es3 "Hola mundo" -w foo.wav
```

please help me